# How to count days between date range with a specifific day?

Tags: oracle11g

How to count days between date range  with a specific day?

**Example:**

START_DT = January 1, 2014;

END_DT = January 31, 2014;

Day = :SampleDay

**Sample Result:**

Monday = 4,

Tuesday = 4,

Wednesday = 5

Please help. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this,

```
WITH t(date1, date2) AS
(
     SELECT to_date('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 
            to_date('31/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')+1 -- Adding 1 to calculate the last day too.
     FROM DUAL
)
     SELECT count(days) day_count, day
            DAY  
     FROM(
          SELECT date1 + LEVEL -1 days, 
                 to_char(date1 + LEVEL -1, 'FmDay') DAY, --Use `FmDay`, this will remove the Embedded spaces.
                 to_char(date1 + LEVEL -1, 'D') DAY#
          FROM   t
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2 - date1
          ) 
     WHERE day = 'Monday' --Filter with day, if you want to get the count for a specific day.
     GROUP BY DAY, day#
     ORDER BY day#;
```

Comment: @VondRitz, just filter the o/p like, `WHERE day = 'Sunday'` I'll update my answer.

Comment: @VondRitz, Use `FmDay` in the query like, `to_char(date1 + LEVEL -1, 'FmDay')` and try. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You wont have a direct solution to this. In oracle you have this form to know what day of the week is a specific date:

```
    to_char(to_date('01012014', 'ddmmyyyy'), 'Day')
```

I would recommend to you to make a store procedure with a simple algorithm which receive that three parameters and then display the information you need. Put it in a query and it is done.